# #include working in .cpp file, but doesn't if I move it to the header

Tags: c++, include, opencl

I have a probably very simple problem regarding including statements in header files.
I've got the following working as intended:

IPlatformHelper.h:

```
#pragma once    
#include <vector>
class IPlatformHelper
{
public:
    virtual int GetNumberOfPlatforms() = 0;
    virtual ~IPlatformHelper() {};
};
```

PlatformHelper.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "IPlatformHelper.h"

class PlatformHelper :
    public IPlatformHelper
{
public:
    PlatformHelper();
    virtual int GetNumberOfPlatforms();
    virtual ~PlatformHelper();
};
```

PlatformHelper.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "PlatformHelper.h"

#include <CL/cl.h>


PlatformHelper::PlatformHelper()
{
}

int PlatformHelper::GetNumberOfPlatforms()
{
    cl_uint numPlatforms;
    cl_platform_id platforms;
    auto result = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platforms, &numPlatforms);
    return (int)numPlatforms;
}

PlatformHelper::~PlatformHelper()
{
}
```

It runs fine, correctly using the method exposed in CL/cl.h.
However, I'd like to add more useful methods to the interface, including methods with signatures involving CL/cl.h classes:

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <CL/cl.h>

class IPlatformHelper
{
public:
    virtual std::vector<cl_platform_id> GetPlatform() = 0;
    virtual int GetNumberOfPlatforms() = 0;
    virtual ~IPlatformHelper() {};
};
```

So I update it to this, and implement the methods in the other files. But this gives me the error:

> "Error    1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl.h': No such file or directory".

All 3 of the files are in the same directory, and intellisense suggests that file when I add the include. 
I've tried adding a forward declaration instead of the include:

```
class cl_platform_id;
```

but this leads to the error

> "Error    1   error C2040: 'cl_platform_id' : '_cl_platform_id *' differs in levels of indirection from 'cl_platform_id'"

Comment: If you change it to `#include "cl/cl.h"` does it make a difference?

Comment: If you're including a header from another header the path will be different. For example if you're including cl/cl.h from the header ab/cd.h you would need to include ../cl/cl.h because you're starting off in the ab subdirectory.

Comment: Afraid not :(, same error.
The .cpp file and .h files are in the same directory (for now at least). I've also added the folder containing this dependency to "Additional Include Directories" to the project, so it should be finding it.

Comment: The only problem I can think of is that the precompiled headers are messing with something. Try disabling them.